# My JS Object iteration broke on addition of new property

Tags: javascript

I have code to iterate the following JS data structure:

```
var data = {
    "features": [
        {
            "photo_id": 27932,
            "longitude": -64.404945,
            "latitude": -32.202924,
            "owner_id": 4483
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

My code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.features[i].latitude, data.features[i].longitude)
}
```

This way works with no problem.

But now, my structure has changed such that I added a property to the `features` objects which is itself an object:

```
var data = {
    "features":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "properties": {
                "Adresse": "7 CHEMIN DES BIOTS 33160 SAINT MEDARD EN JALLES",
                "Index":2,
                "Id":1,
                "longitude":-0.739138,
                "latitude":44.893356
            },
            "type":"Feature"
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

I have try this in java script but he doesn't work :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.features.properties[i].latitude, data.features.properties[i].longitude)
}
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.features[i].properties.latitude, data.features[i].properties.longitude)
}
```

Do you know a way to do this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: your latter way of doing it works fine.. maybe you don't have 11 items. Try replacing 11 in the for defintion with data.features.length

Comment: are you sure your data is a valid object structure?

Comment: Have you tried `alert(data.features[i].properties)` to see what you get?

Comment: 1) That's not JSON. 2) "Doesn't work" is not a description of a problem. What error are you getting? @KenFyrstenberg is on the right track with you...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was java script doesn't display markers

I've checked the code, and now with this method "data.features[i].properties.latitude"    all it's working.

Thanks for your help.